# How do we do Datastore inequality and "IN" filters using the Google Cloud Java API?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

In the AppEngine API, `com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.FilterOperator` supports `NOT_EQUAL` and `IN` queries.

However, in the [Google Cloud API](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries), `com.google.cloud.datastore.StructuredQuery.PropertyFilter` does not support these.

How do we do inequality and *IN* filters in Google Cloud API?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot currently. For historical reasons IN is actually a client side feature first implemented in NDB then ported to Java for App Engine language consistency. IN and NOT_EQUAL are not true server-side features, which is why it is not present in all client libraries.

In the client, IN is split into several queries (one for each value) and then merged on the client side. NOT_EQUAL is similar in that it changes it to less than and greater than queries.

Comment: As a comment, this is being considered for a server side query feature to address the discrepancy.

Comment: Has that feature been implemented since you wrote this comment?